# Wrong order of checkout steps after updating to 2.4.3-p1?

Tags: magento2, checkout

After I did an update to 2.4.3-p1 from 2.2.8 the checkout steps are in the wrong order. Normally you have shipment and the next step is payment.

In my store, its the opposite, first comes payment and shipment is the last step. How would that happen? Any ideas? Is that a setting maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be you did the customization on the core class of the checkout module at 2.2.8 and after upgradations, it is removed.  Magento default feature shipment then payment method. Setting does not manage this feature. You have to customization yourself.

Comment: Yes, it was an extension that someone else installed ... I disabled it and everything is back to normal :-)